# Java: Local Standard Time to Instant

Tags: java, dst, java-time

A service like [this](http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/hourly_data_e.html?hlyRange=1994-02-01%7C2019-06-18&dlyRange=1999-07-19%7C2019-06-18&mlyRange=2004-01-01%7C2007-07-01&StationID=10800&Prov=PE&urlExtension=_e.html&searchType=stnProv&optLimit=yearRange&StartYear=2017&EndYear=2019&selRowPerPage=25&Line=9&lstProvince=PE&timeframe=1&Year=2016&Month=11&Day=6#) has an explicit note that

> All times are specified in Local Standard Time (LST). Add 1 hour to
>   adjust for Daylight Saving Time where and when it is observed.

Given a `LocalDateTime` object `ldt`, creating an instant is as simple as
`Instant.of(ldt,zoneId)`. However, if I supply the `ZoneId`, then `Instant` will assume the daylight-savings (DST) adjustment has already been made, and `ldt` is with respect to DST, which is not the case.
What is the most Java-esque way to make the `Instant`'s constructor apply the "standard" offset rather than taking into account the DST?

EDIT: I mean, short of hard-codedly checking, for the given year, the exact dates of DST transitions? Sure, I can get the offset as
`ZoneOffset offset= ZoneOffset.of(zoneId)` and then subtract  `offset.getTotalSeconds()` from the given timestamp, to move to the "reference" time. But giving that reference-adjusted timestamp to `Instant` still
has the same problem of the DST.

EDIT: As has been suggested below, I tried this:

```java
String str = String.format("%04d-%02d-%02dT%s:00", year, month, day, hourMinutes);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str);
Instant i1= ldt.toInstant(zoneId.getRules().getOffset(ldt));
Instant key= ldt.toInstant(zoneId.getRules().getStandardOffset(i1));
```

Comment: Hi perhaps use `ZoneId.getRules()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the standard offset of a `ZoneId` by calling `getRules()` and then [`getStandardOffset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getStandardOffset-java.time.Instant-).

However, you need an `Instant`. Because sometimes the standard offset changes too...

So one way is to first convert the `LocalDateTime` to `Instant`, using the offset at that `LocalDateTime`. Then we get the standard offset at that instant, and use that to get the actual `Instant` we want:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = ...;
Instant i = ldt.toInstant(someZoneId.getRules().getOffset(ldt));
Instant i2 = ldt.toInstant(someZoneId.getRules().getStandardOffset(i));
System.out.println(i2);
```

I *think* this wouldn't work for some specific local times if both the standard offset and the DST offset changes at the same time, because the first instant `i` is calculated with the offset before the transition. You can calculate `i` with the offset after the transition by doing this:

```
Instant i;
ZoneOffsetTransition transition = someZoneId.getRules().getTransition(ldt)
if (transition == null) {
    i = ldt.toInstant(someZoneId.getRules().getOffset(ldt));
} else {
    i = ldt.toInstant(transition.getOffsetAfter());
}
```

Update:

But even still, this will produce the wrong result for some really corner cases. The problem is that java.time does not provide a way of getting the transitions in standard offset.

Answer (score 0):

The `ZonedDateTime` description states:

> This class handles conversion from the local time-line of
>   LocalDateTime to the instant time-line of Instant. The difference
>   between the two time-lines is the offset from UTC/Greenwich,
>   represented by a ZoneOffset.

Convert the `LocalDateTime` object to `ZonedDateTime` with [`atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) using the zone identifier.

Then call the default [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--) method, which is inherited from the `ChronoZonedDateTime` class, to get an `Instant` object.